# Open select clicking another element with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been looking for a way to open a select / combobox clicking another element. I read  answers saying that is impossible but... How is facebook doing it?

In your facebook timeline, when you want to change the date of a status, there is an ahchor and when you click it, a combobox appears. I thought they had applied styles to their select so it would look like an anchor but it wasn't like that.

Their HTML code has an anchor and a select element, this last one is hidden. Then, I know the select element is positioned as absolute but I can't get from their javascript code how it works.

I tried to simulate it like this

```
$('#element').click();
document.getElementById('element').click();
```

None of this works. I saw a script that duplicated the SELECT element but it add 2 attributes to it: multiple and size. This changes the look of the select.

I would like to know how it would be possible? I know maybe it won't work in IE < 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are talking about this?

```
<span class="period periodDay">
   <a class="uiIconText periodLabel" style="padding-left: 11px;"><img class="img" src="https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v1/yo/r/5-fr6z6ewzf.png" alt="" style="top: 4px;" width="6" height="6" />Tag hinzufügen</a>
   <select data-name="day" class="periodMenu dayMenu" name="backdated_date[day]">
      <option value="">Tag:</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="2">more days...</option>
   </select>
</span>
```

The `<a>` tag is over the `<select>` and the click gets piped through. If you click the link an the right end it does not work.

**Update**

You can use this trick to open the select. Place the select below the anchor and move the anchor after the click.

```
<select id="moveme" style="position: relative;"
    onmousedown="$('#moveme').css('left', '100px');">
  <option value="">Tag:</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="2">more days...</option>
</select>​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HfFWr/1/

Tested in Firefox, Chrome and IE.

Comment: You're right.  I'm an idiot. I guess I didn't see the opacity property on the inspector `opacity: 0` although I said it was hidden . Hmmm. Let say both elements are not in the same position... THAT is impossible, right? Or maybe when it's clicked (select) changing its position will do it?. Thanks.

Comment: Nice idea. I [tried](http://jsfiddle.net/HfFWr/) that! Moving the select does work in Firefox but not in Chrome.

Comment: It doesn't work because I think (I should read) Chrome doesn't recognize onclick for that element. I changed to onmousedown: http://jsfiddle.net/HfFWr/1/ it works!